# Assert function for Dialogue box

Tags: unit-testing

In my application there are 3 textboxes and a button. If a user doesnot fill any of these textboxes and hits the button, a message box is shown to user saying a particular textbox is not entered.

Now how can I use Assert to confirm that message box was popped or not?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Can you specify what your using to deliver the textboxes?

Comment: I am using White to insert the values and click the button.

Answer (score 0):

For this kinds of GUI Unit testing, the cleaner solution is to abstract UI side effects behind an interface.

So instead of calling something like :

```
ShowErrorMessage("This is bad");
```

You create an interface responsible for showing the object

```
public interface MessageShower {
   public function showMessage(String msg);
}
```

In real life, your code will use a concrete implementation :

```
public class ConcreteMessageShower {
   public function showMessage(String msg) {
     ShowErrorMessage(msg);
   }
}
```

However in unit test you will use a fake implementation, or a stub, or a mock.

This is really the general question of "how do I test UI side effect ?", to which the answer is : "you don't !" ;)

Hoping this helps.